# html2canvas Image downloaded is different than in the browser

Tags: html2canvas

Image downloaded is different than in the browser

Browser:
[image]

File downloaded:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs because the box-shadow property,

When I remove `box-shadow` it works as it should.

credit: https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/2056#issuecomment-548168394